# Using Python to group files with similar filenames

Tags: python, pdf, merge, glob

I am trying to write a python script that looks for pdfs in a directory that have similar filenames and combines the pdfs. The files I want to group all start with the same 16 chars, but have different dates in the filename.

#### All of the file names are in this format:

> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_01-01-2019.pdf
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_02-01-2019.pdf
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_03-01_2019.pdf
>
> yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_01-01-2019.pdf
>   yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_02-01-2019.pdf

#### Python Script

```
import glob  
filelist = glob.glob(_filepath_) 

dictionary = {}  
for x in filelist:  
    group = dictionary.get(x[125:141],[])  
    group.append(x)  
    dictionary[x[125:141]] = group
```

This *kinda* works. However, it only returns one file for each like filename:

```
['xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_01-01-2019.pdf','yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_01-01-2019.pdf']
```

If I can solve the grouping of the files, combining the pdfs will not be an issue.

Comment: Sounds like [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) might help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. You need to make a [mre]. I want to write an answer but it seems like the globbing is the problem, and you haven't actually given the glob. As well, the slice `x[125:141]` doesn't make sense (should be `x[:16]`), and your output should be a dict, not a list. FWIW the loop seems to work properly. I tested it with your filenames as a list of strings.

Comment: Yeah it sounds like you just need some basic RegEx.

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you for providing the link to the tour. I will be sure to follow stackoverflow's posting rules next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go

```
filelist = glob.glob(_filepath_) 

dictionary = {}  
for x in filelist:  
    key = x[:16] # The key is the first 16 characters of the file name
    group = dictionary.get(key,[])
    group.append(x)  
    dictionary[key] = group
```

result

```
{
'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_': ['yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_01-01-2019.pdf', 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_02-01-2019.pdf'],
'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_': ['xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_01-01-2019.pdf', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_02-01-2019.pdf', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_03-01_2019.pdf']}
```

Comment: This solution worked. However, I changed the key to `key = os.path.basename(x).split('_')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
import glob  


filelist = glob.glob(_filepath_) 

dictionary = {} 
pattern = r'(.+)(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}.pdf)'
for x in filelist:  
    tmp = re.findall(pattern, x)[0]
    if tmp[0] not in dictionary:
        dictionary[tmp[0]] = [tmp[1]]
    else:
        dictionary[tmp[0]].append(tmp[1])
```